# Ubuntu does not recognize added RAM

Tags: memory, ram

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Ubuntu only show 3GB of RAM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32272/why-does-ubuntu-only-show-3gb-of-ram)

I changed my laptop RAM and went from 3GB to 4GB.  Ubuntu still sees only 3GB, but the
BIOS confirms 4096 MB installed.  How do I get Ubuntu to recognize the added 1GB?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to AskUbuntu. Unfortunately, for us to help you, you need to elaborate some more on your question. For instance what is the version (32 or 64 bits) of your operating system? And if it is 32bits, does your Ubuntu Kernel have PAE enabled?

Comment: Could you please post the output from: `sudo dmidecode -t memory`.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to be running 64 bit kernel, or at lease the pae 32 bit version.  Please give the output of the following:

```
uname -a
```