# How can I tell if a machine has PAE?

Tags: pae

I want to help someone upgrade an oldish laptop from 11.10 to 12.04, which requires PAE. I am not sure whether they have PAE or not.

I know it is likely that they do have it after all, but how can I tell before trying to upgrade?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Citing https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingPAE:

> To check if your processor supports PAE, try
>
> ```
> grep --color=always -i PAE /proc/cpuinfo
> ```

If it outputs something, you have PAE support. Otherwise, the output will be empty.

Comment: But what if you want to know if your computer is PAE capable, but doesn't show the PAE flag?  I understand that many Pentium M and Celeron M processors are like that.  My old Thinkpad T40 laptop is like that.  Is there a way to tell if the capability is there without checking the flag?

Comment: @MarnixA.vanAmmers A quick lookup shows that your Thinkpad T40 has an [Intel Pentium M processor of the Banias family](http://ark.intel.com/products/27577/Intel-Pentium-M-Processor-1_60-GHz-1M-Cache-400-MHz-FSB) which does not report the supported flag even if it is supported according to the [Ubuntu wiki on PAE](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PAE). You can try adding the `forcepae` boot option as described in the wiki.

Answer (score 7):

Another option (which uses a GUI) involves using [Hardinfo (System Profiler and Benchmark](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/hardinfo/).

- Under devices, select Processor.
- From here, you can see the processor's capabilities (along with their simple descriptions).
- If PAE is not listed, your processor does not support it.

[image]

- As you can tell, the processor in this example does not.

[image]

- and this one does.

Comment: Do you also want an image that does support PAE? :+

Comment: @Rinzwind lol I could add one from my other laptop :P

Comment: oh I had one ready @roland >:)

Comment: @Rinzwind Core i5! Argh I only have a Core2Duo :(

Comment: yeah, got it VERY cheap this notebook (even let an i7 go for it: since I got 50% discount on it for it being displayed in the window of the shop). It's a real delight: 1x120Gb ssd and 1x500Gb hdd. Ubuntu starts up in 7 seconds _O-

Answer (score 3):

From the terminal, simply type the following.

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

Scroll down and check the flags. PAE will be listed in the flags if supported.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
inxi -f
```

Or, to see it in red color (if present):

```
inxi -f | grep -i pae
```