# Problem installing Ubuntu on older PC

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu 13.10 32 bit on older PC with only 256MB of RAM but every time it gets to the screen where choice needs to be done between demo and install it just hangs and I can not go any further. Sometimes it hangs even sooner on the purple screen. The mouse get sluggish and clicking on buttons does not do anything.
Is it possible to run this OS on this older PC and if so what steps should I take to get it installed??
If I can not use Ubuntu on this PC can someone recommend another Linux OS which can be used??
Just trying to move away from Windows XP.

Comment: Ubuntu 13.10 [requires](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements#Ubuntu_Desktop_Edition) at least 512Gb of RAM. You should try with [Lubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu) or another lightweight distro of Ubuntu.

Comment: You could also try a non-Ubuntu distro, you can find some choices for older machines [here](http://distrowatch.com/search.php?ostype=All&category=Old+Computers&origin=All&basedon=All&notbasedon=None&desktop=All&architecture=All&status=Active).

Answer (score 0):

The best option you have to get the familiar feel in linux on an older pc is to get Lubuntu. You can download the torrent file from [here](http://www.monova.org/torrent/7069756/Lubuntu_13.10_Desktop_%2832-bit%29.html). I assume you know what to do next ;) :)

Answer (score 0):

Xubuntu 12.04 LTS uses the PAE-required kernel as per [How can I tell if a machine has PAE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128396/how-can-i-tell-if-a-machine-has-pae) and [How can I install on a non-PAE CPU? (error "Kernel requires features not present on the CPU: PAE")](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117744/how-can-i-install-on-a-non-pae-cpu-error-kernel-requires-features-not-present) so may I ask you try Lubuntu 13.10 which will work without PAE.

Comment: Don't you think Lubuntu 13.10 requires PAE?

Comment: Nope. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu-fake-PAE