# How can I install 12.04 LTS on a non-PAE machine?

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, installation, 9.10, windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot install due to the error “Kernel requires features not present on the CPU: PAE”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117744/cannot-install-due-to-the-error-kernel-requires-features-not-present-on-the-cpu)

The other day I started trying out Ubuntu on an ageing Samsung Q30 (like a Dell Latitude X1, apparently). I kept an existing Windows XP installation and allocated 6GB to the Ubuntu partition as I will only be using the Ubuntu for browsing and playing sound files. Here's the order I tried things out and what happened.

**12.04 LTS** -- Won't boot/won't install because of non-PAE.

**10.04 LTS** -- Had the Ubuntu loading screen for a while with the dots moving and the CD drive whirring, then the screen went (and remained) completely black with no hard drive activity and the CD drive also stopped and went silent.

**9.10** -- Worked beautifully! But lumbered with an ancient un-upgradable version of Firefox and it was a battle and a half to get Flash video and MP3 playback capability working given 9.10's advanced years and dead download links.

Realising that 9.10 is not supported any longer. I decided to look up what the non-PAE error was about, and I have learned that it would be possible to get 12.04 LTS via an upgrade from 11.10. "But", I thought, "10.04 LTS didn't work at all, and 12.04 doesn't work, so shall I assume that 11.10 won't work?" Computers being computers, though, I tried doing a boot from CD trial of 11.10 and it **does** work! So I'd like to go ahead with the following if anyone can advise or point to some online instructions for this situation.

I would like to:

- Keep the partitions as they are
- Keep the Windows XP installation as it is and still be able to boot to it when required
- Completely remove 9.10
- Do a completely new install of 11.10 from the CD.

I've only had the Ubuntu for a couple of days and I have no data or settings/personalisations that I need to keep. But I'm really enjoying browsing with Ubuntu (even with an ancient version of Firefox) and find the text rendering for reading online articles much superior to even Windows Cleartype.

Again, many thanks in advance for advice and pointers!

**P.S. The original title** of this question was about how to completely remove 9.10 and replace it with 11.10 (with a view to then being able to upgrade to 12.04). Over the course of the questions and answers, I suggested changing the title to the current one as it now better reflects the content. I hope this is acceptable and provides an explanation to the comment that this is a possible duplicate answer.