# How do you get rid of EFI bios?

Tags: installation, bios, uefi

Well I'm trying to install ubuntu on an old 2003 made computer, the only problem is that it keeps on crashing into a kernel panic. It reverts to the text based installer, and if I takeaway the startup.sh file it doesn't boot at all. That gives me the suspicion that it has EFI bios software, which ubuntu probably isn't compatible with. Is there a way to install ubuntu on old EFI bios, or maybe just a way to update the bios?

Comment: system specifications please?

Comment: Ref the section *Do your homework* in this [*How to Ask*](http://askubuntu.com/questions/how-to-ask) guide.

Comment: If the system is from 2003, is it possible that the CPU doesn't support the PAE feature?  The default kernel on the 12.04 install disc requires a PAE capable processor.  If this is the case, then perhaps http://askubuntu.com/questions/117744/how-can-i-install-12-04-on-a-non-pae-cpu-error-kernel-requires-features-not-p is appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

A 2003 machine will almost certainly not have EFI unless [it has an Itanium processor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#History)

But the machine most probably has low memory. The LiveCD/Desktop Installer may not run well with less than 512 MB of RAM. Please try the Alternate CD instead which is designed for such situations.

Comment: Well I can assure you that the machine has more than 512 MB of RAM. The processor I'm not too sure about, but the more I examine it, the more it seems to be EFI. Just to help prove it, whenever it runs out of boot options, instead of just sitting there and doing nothing, it gives me a command line.

Comment: Ok, I have the details now: Graphics card made in 1999, Processor made in 1998, RAM made in 2000/2001, Motherboard made in 1999.