# How to install ubuntu 12.04 without Physical Address Extension?

Tags: 12.04, pae

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot install due to the error “Kernel requires features not present on the CPU: PAE”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117744/cannot-install-due-to-the-error-kernel-requires-features-not-present-on-the-cpu)

Physical Extension Memory is required in my computer to install ubuntu 12.04 in my laptop.
I don't know how pae is upgraded in laptop. Is there any other solution to install ubuntu 12.04?