# why do I get a PAE error trying to install 12.04 desktop 32 bit version on an IBM Thinkpad T42

Tags: 12.04, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install 12.04 on a non-PAE CPU? (error “Kernel requires features not present on the CPU: PAE”)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117744/how-can-i-install-12-04-on-a-non-pae-cpu-error-kernel-requires-features-not-p)

I have downloaded the 32 bit version of ubuntu 12.04 from the site and when I try to do a clean install on the computer it gives me the PAE error saying the processor cannot address 64 gig of memory. The 32 bit version I downloaded should not be looking for that function.

Answer (score 1):

Your machine is rather old (2005?) and does not support certain extensions the recent versions of Ubuntu kernel require.

From [How To Install Ubuntu 12.04 On Non-PAE Capable Hardware](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/05/how-to-install-ubuntu-1204-on-non-pae.html)

> Physical Address Extension (PAE) is a feature to allow (32-bit) x86
>   processors to access a physical address space (including random access
>   memory and memory mapped devices) larger than 4 gigabytes.
>
> Ubuntu 12.04 (as well as Kubuntu 12.04) uses the PAE Linux kernel by
>   default for 32bit ISOs so old computers that don't support PAE can't
>   boot the latest Ubuntu version. But there is a way to install Ubuntu
>   12.04 LTS Precise Pangolin on computers without PAE support: using the non-PAE netboot Minimal ISO (there are also some alternatives, see
>   below).
>
> The non-PAE netboot mini ISO lets you install the non-PAE kernel and
>   the desktop environment you want: you can select to install Ubuntu
>   Desktop (with Unity), Kubuntu Desktop and so on. One note though:
>   since the minimal CD will download packages from online archives at
>   installation time instead of providing them on the install CD itself,
>   you need a working Internet connection during the installation.