# Lubuntu 12.10 This kernel does not support a non-PAE CPU

Tags: kernel, dell, lubuntu, non-pae

I have a Dell Inspiron 600m and I tried to install Lubuntu 12.10 but encountered this message:

> This kernel does not support a non-PAE CPU.

Is Lubuntu supposed to support old hardware and computers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install on a non-PAE CPU? (error "Kernel requires features not present on the CPU: PAE")](http://askubuntu.com/questions/117744/how-can-i-install-on-a-non-pae-cpu-error-kernel-requires-features-not-present)

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to trick the apt-get installation script (preinst) of the new kernel images into *believing* they are to be installed on a PAE enabled System. Then it will install flawlessly (and if it is a Pentium-M (even one of those early ones that are missing the pae flag) then it will boot and run without errors).

To do so do the following:

- Install 12.04 Precise (maybe you have that already)
- Install the package "fake-pae" from [this repository](https://launchpad.net/~prof7bit/+archive/fake-pae)
- Do a normal distribution upgrade to 12.10 and enjoy the new Version :-)

As long as you have the fake-pae package installed there won't be any problems with kernel updates, these kernels run just fine on Pentium-M, even the early ones that do not announce their pae capability in their cpu flags. Just like the modified CD-boot images (the grub-trick) it is only a matter of circumventing these artificial installation restrictions, its not a problem with the kernel itself, you won't need custom built kernel images.

Answer (score 2):

Try to install [Lubuntu 12.04 32bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/12.04/release/) and then upgrade to 12.10

Inspired by this answer : [How can I install on a non-PAE CPU? (error "Kernel requires features not present on the CPU: PAE")](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117744/how-can-i-install-12-04-on-a-non-pae-cpu-error-kernel-requires-features-not-p)

Answer (score 0):

Installing Lubuntu 12.04 32 bit and upgrading to 12.10 (cf. answer by NikTh) does not seem to work fully: The default kernel for 12.10 does not install.

You might be able to get the custom non-pae kernel from: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~webtom/+junk/linux-image-i386-non-pae/files (I did not try this out.)

See also: [Will it be possible to use a non-pae kernel in recent versions of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182048/will-it-be-possible-to-use-a-non-pae-kernel-in-12-10)