# Upgrading to Xubuntu 12.10 using a Non-PEA supported CPU

Tags: kernel, 12.10, pae

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will it be possible to use a non-pae kernel in 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182048/will-it-be-possible-to-use-a-non-pae-kernel-in-12-10)

I have just been upgrading my Xubuntu 12.04 system to Xubuntu 12.10. However I've got several error message during the upgrading process. At the end I was left with two broken packages: linux-image-extra-3.5.0-17-generic and linux-image-generic.

Trying to reinstall them gives me the following error message:

```
This kernel does not support a non-PAE CPU.
```

I have found the following posts:

http://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg3868794.html

https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2012-May/035176.html

Do I understand them right that my CPU is not supported anymore? Is there any other way to fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Btw: I'm using a IBM Thinkpad T42 containing an Intel Pentium M 1.7 GHz. It surely is not the newest system, however I think not that old to completely stop the support.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is true. Lubuntu and Xubuntu 12.04 LTS were the last releases supporting a non-PAE CPU by providing a 32-bit non-pae kernel as can be read from the [release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/Xubuntu):

> The i386 images use a non-PAE kernel. The non-PAE kernel will not be available in future Xubuntu releases.

Therefore it is recommended to stay with the 12.04 long term release on an old system which does not support [PAE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19389/whats-the-meaning-of-pae-at-the-end-of-kernel-version?rq=1). This release will be fully supported until [end of 2017](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS).

See also this question:

- [How to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version)

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to downgrade from 12.10 to 12.04 again?

Comment: There hopefully haven't been made any changes to the settings files in you HOME because you were unable to boot. Therefore it should be safe to re-install from a Xubuntu 12.04 CD/USB. In case you have a separate HOME partition it's easy: just take care not to format it.  Otherwise you should **backup the HOME directory** before you proceed and restore it later. You will **not** have the usual option to install without erasing HOME in case there is a 12.10 installation present! **Disclaimer:** I have not tested this, so I cant tell for sure that its safe.