# Intel Pentium M with Ubuntu 12.10 / PPA needed

Tags: apt

I need the ppa too. I've updated yet my Thinkpad T42 from Lubuntu 12.04 to 12.10. Everytime I want to install or update something I get this error:

```bash
E: Unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten. Versuchen Sie 
apt-get -f install« ohne Angabe eines Pakets (oder geben Sie eine Lösung an).
```

if I try `apt-get -f install` I earn this:

```bash
/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.5.0-17-generic_3.5.0-17.28_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Is there a possibility to use 12.10 with Intel Pentium M Processors?

Comment: non-pae kernel for ubuntu 12.10:
you find the ppa here:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/182048/will-it-be-possible-to-use-a-non-pae-kernel-in-12-10
volker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an alternative. The T42 **will** definitely run with official PAE-Kernels (this is also good news for owners of R40, R50, R51, R52, X31, X32, X40, X41, T40, T41, T42, T43)

- install the package fake-pae from [this repository](https://launchpad.net/~prof7bit/+archive/fake-pae)
- reinstall that broken package linux-image-3.5.0-17-generic, this time it will install without errors. Also then let it reconfigure all other packages that depend on it, it should work and bring your package system back into a consistent state with the new 3.5 kernel happily installed.
- then reboot with your new kernel, everything should be ok, also all subsequent kernel upgrades should now work as long as you leave the fake-pae package installed on your system.

Answer (score 1):

possibility to use 12.10 with Intel Pentium M Processors:

-installed lubuntu 12.04 with generic (non-PAE) 3.2.0-33 standard kernel (as virtual machine under VB) on dell D505 (Pentium-M),

- upgraded to 12.10 using "apt pinning" to avoid problems with the generic (PAE) 3.5 kernel,
- after removing again apt pinning, installed the non-PAE 3.5 kernel from the PPA as referenced above.

Everything appears to work.
volker

Answer (score 0):

Use fake-PAE according to these links

[Lubuntu-fake-PAE](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu-fake-PAE)

[PAE](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PAE)