# How to do a fresh install of 12.04 on non-PAE CPU PC?

Tags: 12.04, installation, pae, non-pae

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install 12.04 on a non-PAE CPU? (error “Kernel requires features not present on the CPU: PAE”)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117744/how-can-i-install-12-04-on-a-non-pae-cpu-error-kernel-requires-features-not-p)

I can not install 12.04 Desktop on non-PAE CPU PC. Keep getting error message on missing CPU feature. I prefer alternate install CD.

Thanks