# Why is 12.04.1 "unable to boot"

Tags: 12.04, kernel, pae

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install 12.04 on a non-PAE CPU? (error “Kernel requires features not present on the CPU: PAE”)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117744/how-can-i-install-12-04-on-a-non-pae-cpu-error-kernel-requires-features-not-p)

I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04.1 for the first time on my laptop. When I select "Install on disk", it gives me this error message.

```
This kernel requires the following features not present on the CPU; pae
Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU.
```

I get this message both when attempting to install from a USB drive and a CD.

Just in case it matters, my laptop is a Dell Inspiron 600m. It has an Intel Pentium M chip.

Comment: Please see this answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/117744/how-can-i-install-12-04-on-a-non-pae-cpu-error-kernel-requires-features-not-p