# ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-i386, boot error, wrong kernel

Tags: boot, cd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install 12.04 on a non-PAE CPU? (error “Kernel requires features not present on the CPU: PAE”)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117744/how-can-i-install-12-04-on-a-non-pae-cpu-error-kernel-requires-features-not-p)

Just down loaded version ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-i386 for intel/windows. Built bootable CD, getting error, "this Kernel requires the following features not present on the CPU: pae
Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU. My system in an older IBM ThinkPad  T40.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can download the [lubuntu](http://lubuntu.org) LiveCD and install that since it has a non-PAE kernel. You can then open the Terminal and run :

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

to install the Ubuntu UI and window manager. It may take a while since Ubuntu-desktop actually needs a lot of packages.

Comment: I'd refrain from posting on questions that have a "possible duplicate" comment on them since they might be closed. This is just for future reference.

Comment: ObsessiveFOSS I'll try to be more ca\reful. hanks for telling me about this.

Comment: I searched, I did not find a similar post, my error. Thanks for the  link, I'm testing now...