# PAE Kernel Error while Installing 12.04

Tags: kernel, 12.10, pae

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install 12.04 on a non-PAE CPU? (error “Kernel requires features not present on the CPU: PAE”)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117744/how-can-i-install-12-04-on-a-non-pae-cpu-error-kernel-requires-features-not-p)

Tried to install Ubuntu 12.04 but getting an error: this kernel requires the following features not present on the CPU: PAE unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU.

How do i resolve this?