# Screen remains dark after installing Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric) on Samsung X10

Tags: boot, system-installation, samsung

After successfully running the live CD and testing WiFi and other things, I decided to install Ubuntu as a single operating system on my Samsung X10 laptop. At this point everything seemed okay, installation took a couple of hours and I completed it.

Starting the X10 from HDD with Ubuntu shows an Ubuntu screen and then an option to press <kbd>s</kbd> or .... but it is too fast to read. The system seems to boot, but the screen remains dark after the hint. The HDD led lights up while moving the mouse cursor using touchpad, but the screen still remains dark. I can ping my PC on network, but that's about it.

No newer Ubuntu install possible, because x10 does not support pae. External display via vga-port is working. Display is flagged unknown and I am not in a position to change resolution (to see the whole system settings screen) nor to choose or install drivers for another display.

---

Regarding "Have you tried this one? [How can I install on a non-PAE CPU?](http://askubuntu.com/q/117744/88802)", I want to run all PCs with same Ubuntu (30+) in the initial starting phase. It's a workgroup in an elementary school and we have to rely on donated hardware. Also, it does not answer the question why the live operation from DVD works perfectly and the final installation does not recognise the display and the graphics card. Even with the external crt, it is not possible to change resolution. Also it is not possible to change ip-address of wlan ...no sufficient rights. I tried debian, knoppix and mint before ...even worse. If all were arm cpus, I'd take meego ..smoothly even on weaker arms.

Sorry, I cannot answer the other comments.

Comment: Any specific reason for starting out with an older Ubuntu release? Please try installing the latest stable release (12.10) or latest Long Term Support (12.04) release.

Comment: Support for 11.10 will end in April. It is recommended that you install 12.04 or 12.10.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve the issue myself. Despite having a Nvidia Graphics Card, I deleted 3rd party Nvidia drivers which were automatically added by the install procedure. It was hard work though because I had to guess the buttons reached by <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> -- some trial and error. Everything's fine now. Much slower than expected, but suits my basic needs.

Comment: oh, by the way: xubuntu also needs pae despite description saying other way

Comment: Please don't include personal opinions and keep to the point of the actual answer (solution). This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. Also, just accept the fact that you have very specific hardware which is not supported *by design* in Ubuntu (the PAE story).