# Ubuntu 12.10 does not boot on Dell D600

Tags: boot, usb, dell

I have an old Dell Latitude D600 using USB boot Ubuntu 12.10.  When booting, it said that I have the wrong kernal for my CPU.  Very odd, Ubuntu 11.10 was working just fine.  I tried the 12.10 on another PC (newer Dell), and it works.  Not sure what is going on here.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the first answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117744/how-can-i-install-on-a-non-pae-cpu-error-kernel-requires-features-not-present). It explains the problem and offers 3 different solutions!

`The error message means that your CPU does not support PAE extensions - that is a technique which allows a 32bit CPU to address more than 4GB of memory address space.
By default, 12.04 and later versions of Ubuntu expects a CPU with this capability.`