# Installing Ubuntu on an older laptop

Tags: laptop, intel, centrino

I am trying to install Ubuntu on an older laptop. I made a bootable CD and restarted the computer. The following error came up:

This kernel requires the following features not present on the CPU:
pae
Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try Lubuntu - but you would need a RAM with at least 128 MB size. Oh ? you have Centrino ? I tried that 1 month ago too - and succeeded only with Debian 7.0 stable, with boot-option (TAB-key at booting) to add to it in line below: edd=off

Comment: Hello Vicky, Welcome to AskUbuntu. Do you mind providing the information of your computer? such as the brand name/generic, model, and (if possible) make/model of certain components (Microprocessor/Motherboard/Amount of RAM, etc.) in order to get the best support for you? We'll also need to know which version are you trying to use for the install: 32 or 64 bit? 12.04? Older? As @dschinn1001 mentions, a light desktop environment will run smoothly in older computers, of which I will suggest you XUbuntu for stability. Provide us with that information and I am sure we'll find a solution together.

Comment: Solution in this question.. http://askubuntu.com/questions/117744/how-can-i-install-on-a-non-pae-cpu-error-kernel-requires-features-not-present

Comment: Hi. Thanks for you help! Here is the information I have for that laptop. It is an Acer Travelmate 4500. It has a 16GB internal harddrive (which windows is currently filling up). It has 1.25GB of RAM. The Processor is an Intel Pentium M Processor 1.60Ghz. I tried installing Ubuntu 12.4 32 bit from a bootable CD but with no luck. I haven't tried the XUbuntu yet. Is it the same install process?

Comment: Hi Vicky. Well, first of all: we are talking a really old computer, which may result in a laggy/choppy performance even with a light desktop environment. Additionally, you may succeed if you use an older version. Unfortunately I must warn that older versions may be currently obsolete and you will receive no support at all here. Anyway we need to know if you succeeded running a live session on your system in order to know where the problem begins thus provide a solution. Thank you.

Comment: Hi. So I tried Xubuntu but with no luck. Maybe the computer is just too old?

Comment: Hi. Well no, the specs you mentioned in your previous comment seems promissory to install both Ubuntu or XUbuntu. Your problem seems to be in the microprocessor itself, which seems not to feature the "PAE Extension". I suggest you to take a look at this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/117751/9598 and the workarounds mentioned on it in order to see which of these fix your issue. Of which I suggest you the "Install a previous version and then upgrade to 12.04". Other answers in the same question are also useful. Please let us know how are you managing this issue.