# install 13.04 from usb on dell inspiron 600m

Tags: 13.04

I am trying to boot from a usb drive.  I created the usb on an ACER running Win 7 Home premium.  I used the ubuntu-13.04-desktop-1386 using the universal USB installer.  I am trying to install on a Dell inspiron 600m.  When I try to boot, I get a message "SYSLINUX 4.06 EDD 2012-10-23 copyright (C) 1994-2012 H. Peter Anvin et al"
The next line has a blinking underscore.  It will not allow me to enter anything.

What do I do?
Did I try to use the wrong version Linux?
If so, what should I use?

I don't care which version from 12.04 - 13.04 I load.  I couldeven use an earlier version if it will work.  I just want it to boot, so I can install linux as the only OS on this machine.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can re-install the live usb using the same version (Ubuntu 13.04), although I'd suggest using Ubuntu 12.4.2 if you will be using it for a long time.

Some things to consider. Is your hardware / BIOS set to use UEFI?
If so, change it in the BIOS settings and / or select the proper way to mount the USB via the BIOS boot selection.

Have you set the bios to boot from the USB?
This also can be done via the BIOS settings.

As long as the version you are trying to use is listed on the Universal USB Installer, everything should work on that end. Re-install it on the USB and give it another go.

Also, check out the answers on the possible duplicate tag above.

Answer (score 0):

I also have an inspiron 600m.

Unfortunately I didn't have the same problem, so I can't help you directly. But I can tell you that the newer versions of Ubuntu will not work on this machine: They require something called [PAE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117744/how-can-i-install-on-a-non-pae-cpu-error-kernel-requires-features-not-present), which your computer processor does not support.

My solution to this problem was to finally buy a new laptop (after waiting 7 years). [This](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009F1I16K) is what I purchased, if you're interested - it's cheap and lightweight, and comes with Ubuntu preinstalled.

The 12.04 version of Ubuntu (I'd reccomend either Xubuntu or Lubuntu) should work on your machine, and should be supported until March 2014, but won't be supported after that. You could try installing a different linux distribution that still supports non-PAE hardware, such as Debian.