# Boot off of Ubuntu 12.04 using old kernel

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, ppa, pae

Here's the thing, I was resizing my partition and gparted crashed (I was running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Windows XP SP3 dual boot), so now my computer won't boot. I wanted to try and use the PPA boot-repair to help my computer boot,  so I:

1. Booted off of my original Ubuntu 11.10 CD and tried to install the PPA boot-repair by yannubuntu, but sadly boot-repair isn't compatible with 11.10.
2. Downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 and put that on a thumb drive so I could use boot-repair, but my computer won't boot off of that because it is kind of old and doesn't support PAE.

I want to be able to use my computer again, if I understand correctly, I can only get Ubuntu 12.04 if I upgrade from 11.10 because of the PAE issue. Is there a way around this? Can I somehow make the thumb drive boot from ubuntu 12.04 but use a older kernel that doesn't need PAE? I know that my computer can run 12.04 because it worked before.

Thanks a lot, DeveloperNewb

Edit: Is it possible to deceive boot-repair into thinking I have ubuntu 12.04 so I can run it in 11.10?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/117751/164093), 32-bit [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/) 12.04 doesn't expect PAE by default. You should be able to create a bootable USB and load boot-repair/install from that.

Comment: It's fine, I gave up and re-installed Ubuntu 11.10, then I'm gonna update to Ubuntu 12.04 and use boot-repair. Thanks for the tip though.