# How to run Ubuntu after installing it on Lubuntu OS?

Tags: 13.04, lubuntu, pae

I had the problem of PAE kernel discussed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117744/how-can-i-install-on-a-non-pae-cpu-error-kernel-requires-features-not-present)

I decided to do as described in the first workaround by installing Lubuntu.

After I finished installing Lubuntu, I ran the `sudo apt-get install ubunutu-desktop` and after some minutes it finished installing ( I guess).

Now I don't know, how can I start the Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to log out your desktop and select the Ubuntu session under your user name in your login screen.

Answer (score 0):

While your computer is booting, hold `shift`. If you see message GRUB Loading, you know you did it well.

In the GRUB menu, see if you have more than one OS. If you do, boot the one you want to, and if you don't, well it is gonna take more time.

**Case 1**

Your chosen system will boot, and you will be happy :)

**Case 2**

If you don't see the second OS, go to the OS you see (probably Lubuntu) and when it boots, run  in terminal

```
sudo update-grub
```

It should find the second OS and add it to fstab file.

When it's done, reboot and try to get to GRUB again. If you still don't see second OS, then it looks like the second one is not bootable. You might have to get GParted  Live and copy all your data somewhere safe and reinstall.