# Install Lubuntu 14.04 LTS on a non-pae processor

Tags: lubuntu, non-pae

How can I install Lubuntu 14.04 LTS on a non-pae processor?
If it's not possible. Is there a work around for how to do it?
It should be possible. Lubuntu is very low in system resources and perfect for old machines with a non-pae processor.

Comment: What processor do you have? How do you install lubuntu?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install on a non-PAE CPU? (error "Kernel requires features not present on the CPU: PAE")](http://askubuntu.com/questions/117744/how-can-i-install-on-a-non-pae-cpu-error-kernel-requires-features-not-present)

Answer (score 3):

I am refurbishing a number of Pentium M laptops. Intel chose to disable PAE in these chips.
I have used the "forcepae" command with mixed results.

This is how you do it using Lubuntu 14.04 LTS:

- Boot from the live CD and after you chose the language, and get the next screen
- HIGHLIGHT `Install Lubuntu`
- Press <kbd>F6</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd> and then add "forcepae" (no quotes) to the command line
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

You get a warning and it may work about 30% of the time.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, you need to boot the Live USB with the **forcepae** boot option and then add this option to your boot options in GRUB in the installed system to make the change permanent.

Comment: OK. But I'am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Any tutorials or how to do it?

Comment: Have a look here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions#Changing_the_CD_Boot_Option_Configuration_Line As in the screenshot you just add the option after the "--" in the command line.

Comment: This is more a question than an answer. I have an Eden CPU, I tried Lubuntu 14.04 with the forcepae option, but it does not boot. On the same machine I can install lubuntu 12.04. So is forcepae exactly forcing pae which is good for Pentium M? If so what do you do with a real non pae cpu?

Comment: More details here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PAE

Comment: @JonHoffmann forcepae is for enabling PAE on CPUs that say they do not have PAE but actually do. Ubuntu only supports PAE kernels now. If your CPU really does not have PAE then you could try Debian, which still supports 486.

Answer (score 1):

try using Lubuntu grub-n-iso swap img.(burn it to usb stick)
Then boot it into the live session.
you  replace the lubuntu iso stored in it's img file with 14.4 iso.
but you have to rename it to lubuntu.iso.

after replacing the lubuntu.iso file with your iso ,then reboot the Lubuntu grub-n-iso swap img.
From the live session u have running, just click "install" and instead of installing lubuntu it will install from your 14.4 iso.

NOTE:It was for a Dell D505 laptop ,which i think is pae capable but reports as non pae. 
i wrote about it a while ago here:

http://forum.peppermintos.com/index.php?topic=654.0

Answer (score 0):

I admin some Pentium M notebooks. I have two CDs: 12.04 LTS NoPAE and 14.04 LTS Alternate.
First, I install 12.04. Second, I install fake-PAE or build alternate kernel. Third, I run upgrade script from 14.04 CD. LTS-to-LTS upgrade works, but only with a CD, not with web-upgrade.