# No hard drive detected Lubuntu 12.04?

Tags: boot, system-installation

I'm trying to install Lubuntu 12.04 on this old computer I got from someone because they're planning on using it for college but it's old as holy flip.

It's a Dell Latitude X300 with a Pentium M processor from 2003 I think it has like 128MegaBytes of RAM. It originally came with Windows XP Professional SP1 I think.

Anyway, first I tried installing Lubuntu 14.04 but it said it couldn't because of this error:

```
This kernel requires the following features not present on the CPU:
pae

Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU.
```

I found out the the fix is to use an older version of Ubuntu that supported non pae CPU's, so I tried Lubuntu 12.04 which does not detect my drive at all. I tried using PuppyLinux, but puppylinux gives an error, it detects the drive as a 30gb volume but it won't let me use it because it doesn't have a partition table and it won't let me create one either....

Anyone know how to get Linux installed on one of these? This computer is so old I know people have done it, I've seen posts about it, but there's no tutorial or anything.

I tried booting off of USB and for some reason it doesn't like my USB's, so I had to boot off a live USB. I appologize for this block of text but I have no idea, I'm really stumped.

Answer (score 0):

You may yet be able to install Lubuntu 14.04, but there is a special option for PAE.  See [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PAE) and [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingPAE).

This question on AskUbuntu has a [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/117751/67335) that might also help.