# Adding forcepae to bootable usb stick from ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, pae

I have a Dell D400 laptop with 512mb of RAM. (A 2gb upgrade is on the way.)

The laptop is running Ubuntu 12.04 but has some issues (like the apparent absence of any of the wireless networking libraries; either they're not installed or disabled and the Panda Wireless USB adaptor isn't getting picked up by the system)

I have downloaded ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso from [the ubuntu.com site](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/) and using the Startup Disk Creator to "burn" the ISO to the USB drive.

When I boot from the USB stick I get the following message:

> ERROR: PAE is disabled on this Pentium M   (PAE can potentially be
>   enabled with kernel parameter   "forcepae" - this is unsupported, may
>   cause unknown problems, and will taint the kernel)   This kernel
>   requires the following features not present on the CPU:   pae   Unable
>   to boot - please use the appropriate kernel

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install on a non-PAE CPU? (error "Kernel requires features not present on the CPU: PAE")](http://askubuntu.com/questions/117744/how-can-i-install-on-a-non-pae-cpu-error-kernel-requires-features-not-present)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have flagged this as a duplicate question - specifically for your system, [look at this link](https://askubuntu.com/a/117751/283721), workaround #4

You may find very poor performance with Ubuntu 14.04.1 on your system:  The small amount of RAM that you have, along with the Pentium M processor may yield less performance than you want.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! #4 solved my problem. And yes, we're a week away from a memory upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

People who are intending to use Grub4DOS and iso image on USB stick might use this for reference to prepare their Grub entry: People who are intending to use Grub4DOS and iso image on USB stick might use this for reference to prepare their Grub menu entry: [How to configure Grub4dos menu to boot 16.04.5 i386 iso on non- PAE CPU (forcepae)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1115613/how-to-configure-grub4dos-menu-to-boot-16-04-5-i386-iso-on-non-pae-cpu-forcepa)