# How to upgrade from Ubuntu 9.04 to Lubuntu 14.10?

Tags: boot, upgrade, lubuntu

I have an old laptop with 256 MB RAM, which does not boot from USB nor does it boot CD created from ISO.

Only Ubuntu distribution that I managed to boot and install was an old 9.04 Ubuntu that I received as the original CD that was distributed back then.

Now I have the 9.04 installed. How can I upgrade the system to Lubuntu 14.10? I am not very skilled with Linux so I would appreciate if anyone could write few steps to follow (if possible).

Kindly thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading - you'd have to upgrade to 9.10, then 10.04, 12.04, 14.04 and 14.10. It might be much quicker to simply reinstall.

Comment: If you can access the BIOS settings, have you checked whether you can change the boot devices or their order there? Maybe this way you can get it to boot from a CD.

Comment: That looks like a very old machine with very little RAM, below the minimum hardware specifications. If 14.10 runs at all it will be slow. Your best option may well be lubuntu and you may have an old processor that is not supported. see http://askubuntu.com/questions/117744/how-can-i-install-on-a-non-pae-cpu-error-kernel-requires-features-not-present

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements#Ubuntu_Desktop_Edition

Comment: "nor does it boot CD created from ISO" Then how did you install the 9.04 disk back then?

Comment: A fresh install is going to be faster and more reliable then any sort of upgrade process.

Comment: @xangua - depend on why it will not boot. My guess is he has an old CPU that is no longer supported (non-pae)