# I am very new to Ubuntu, so should I try Xubuntu and Lubuntu first?

Tags: xubuntu, lubuntu

I am very new to Ubuntu. The reason I came here and asked the question is that I lost my windows XP CD for my old laptop. My laptop has a P4 CPU, 1GB RAM and 50GB HDD (7200 rpm). I googled for the alternative OS to XP, and there were at least thousands of results returned. Yet, some of the experts in forum (MakeUseOf) recommended Xubuntu and Lubuntu. [Here is the link](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/windows-xp-users-switch-ubuntu-14-04-lts-trusty-tahr/):

But I am lost. What are Xubuntu and Lubuntu? Are they better than Ubuntu alone? I am just looking for a free OS with rich UI and easy to use for my old laptop.

Comment: This question has already been answered as said above. For your use-case I'd recommend Xubuntu or Ubuntu Mate. Lubuntu is quite difficult to use as a new user. Things like changing time require opening the commandline.

Comment: That machine is going to run slow no matter what you do and the CPU may not be supported (you will get an error during boot see - http://askubuntu.com/questions/117744/how-can-i-install-on-a-non-pae-cpu-error-kernel-requires-features-not-present. Your choice of desktop is not going to make firefox run any faster. The only desktop I would avoid would be Unity or gnome-shell as they  are more demanding of your graphics card.

Comment: Hi all, thank you for the suggestion. Sorry for my late reply.