# Can't install Ubuntu without PAE

Tags: 14.04, 14.10, 15.04, 32-bit

I have a laptop with a Pentium M, I need to know how to enable PAE. I have already tried forcepae it messed up somethings like the cursor.

Comment: Try [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/117744/178596). According to Wikipedia and [the Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PAE), only the Banias family of Pentium (and Celeron) M cpus support PAE (or forcing it). You probably only need to enable PAE if you have a large amount of RAM.

Comment: @Wilf: Ubuntu doesn't run any more if you don't have PAE extensions, regardless of your memory size... **:-(**

Comment: I did this a couple of years ago on a Pentium M laptop. You can install Ubuntu 11.10, then update to 12.04 or higher. I couldn't get it to work past that due to video hardware incompatibility. Check [How can I install on a non-PAE CPU? (error “Kernel requires features not present on the CPU: PAE”)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/117744/how-can-i-install-on-a-non-pae-cpu-error-kernel-requires-features-not-present)

Comment: @Fabby well thats stupid because 32bit is probably only needed for machines that don't support PAE - I thought Xubuntu/Lubuntu work without PAE.... (I have a 32bit intel atom netbook happily running Xubuntu 14.04, so it should work....)

Comment: @Wilf: Don't shoot the messenger!  **;-)** Canonical should recompile the kernel without PAE extensions: the kernel itself still supports none...

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu will not normally work on this old computer either way.

Try to install Lubuntu 14.04

[Read this regarding PAE](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu/AdvancedMethods#Pentium_M_and_Celeron_M)

You can't enable PAE, if your CPU does not support it.

Comment: Lubuntu requires PAE in 15.04 which is installed right now on the laptop

Comment: What version of Ubuntu or other OS would you recommend then?

Comment: @JacobBernardis From Ubuntu family you could try Lubuntu 14.04. How much RAM you have?

Comment: about 494 MB of RAM

Comment: It is JUST enough for Lubuntu.

Comment: Yah but Lubuntu is running in forcepae so some parts of Lubuntu doesn't look right

Answer (score 0):

The non-PAE npae124-text-9w lets you install the non-PAE kernel and the desktop environment you want: Xubuntu Desktop - Xfce *(that I suggest)*, Lubuntu Desktop - Lxd.

Download npae124-text-9w from: [Here](http://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/9w/obi_Trusty-nonpae-txt5-9w.iso)

Burn it to a CD or USB drive.

Boot your computer from the the npae124-text-9wiso and select Install at the prompt. You can then follow the instructions.

After booting into this installed Ubuntu mini system with a text interface, if you wish, install a desktop environment.

[Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/9w)

[Download site](http://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/9w/)

## Edited

***How to install Xfce desktop.***

Reboot – remove the Cd/Usb drive.

Login using your username and password.

Run in the terminal

```
$ sudo -i
# apt-get update
# apt-get dist-upgrade
# apt-get install xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-core xfonts-base xinit x11-xserver-utils xfwm4 xfce4-panel xfce4-settings xfce4-session xfce4-terminal xfdesktop4 xfce4-taskmanager tango-icon-theme lightdm lightdm-gtk-greeter thunar gvfs gvfs-backends policykit-1 udisks2 gstreamer0.10-plugins-base gstreamer0.10-plugins-good gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad pulseaudio gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio pavucontrol
```

Comment: And how can I get the desktop environment?

Comment: by apt-get, I edit the post.