# Trying to install Xbuntu on an old laptop with Celeron Processor

Tags: system-installation

I have created two or three bootable CD's from downloads, one with Ubuntu 15.1 and one from mini.iso.  I either get a message that there is some problem with PAE which I have no idea how to deal with, or I get a BOOT: prompt after an ISOLINUX message statement mentioning Peter Alvin.  I have absolutely NO IDEA what I am supposed to do with this.  The bootable CD doesn't just start installing Ubuntu like I hoped it would.  What do I do with the BOOT: prompt?  or the PAE message?

Comment: The original Celeron might not support Physical Address Extension, which is a feature in newer CPU's for increasing the possible addressing space for memory. PAE is now required for normal Ubuntu installation, but I would visit the web site in the comment http://askubuntu.com/questions/117744/how-can-i-install-on-a-non-pae-cpu-error-kernel-requires-features-not-present