# I want to load ubuntu on a old Sony Vaio V505 pentium M 1.7 ghz....What flavor would work?

Tags: versions, sony

I am new to Ubuntu...Want to use this as a web browser and DVD player

Comment: You left out a key number RAM.

Comment: you will need something that address not having the  PAE flag on the pentium M - http://askubuntu.com/questions/117744/how-can-i-install-on-a-non-pae-cpu-error-kernel-requires-features-not-present

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your model has 512MB of RAM, then [**Lubuntu 16.04**](http://lubuntu.me/) 32-Bit would fit the most. If it has 1GB of RAM, then [**Ubuntu MATE**](https://ubuntu-mate.org/) 32-Bit. However, maybe even with 1GB of RAM Lubuntu would be best.