# Where can I download Lubuntu 12.04?

Tags: lubuntu

I need a non-PAE version of Lubuntu (to run on a Fit-PC Slim w/ an AMD GX3 LX800 CPU). I believe 12.04 is the latest version that is non-PAE, but the link on [Lubuntu/PreviousReleases - Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/PreviousReleases#A12.04) doesn't work. Does anyone know where the archived versions of the distro have gone?

Answer (score 12):

You can get outdated and no longer supported Ubuntu releases from http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases

The latest 12.04 release images specifically can be found [here](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04.4/).

---

However, [How can I install on a non-PAE CPU? (error "Kernel requires features not present on the CPU: PAE")](https://askubuntu.com/q/117744/367990) suggests that even 12.04 requires PAE already, meaning you'd have to go even further back to e.g. 10.04.

Also please note that the package repositories got moved to the old-releases server as well, which makes you unable to download and install any packages at first. Have a look at [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release) for that.

Anyway, installing an unsupported operating system is **really not advisable**. You'll get no updates or security patches, have to rely on old software versions, etc.

---

Instead, I'd recommend you to look for a more modern, still supported operating system, that supports no-PAE CPUs. An example would be [PuppyLinux/XenialPup](http://wikka.puppylinux.com/Xenialpup) 32-bit:

> Xenialpup 7.5 uses Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial Xerus packages and includes the bugfixes and improvements from the Woof CE build system. It is compatible with Ubuntu 16.04 packages. The Linux kernel version is 4.4.95-noPAE for the 32-bit version and 4.9.58 for the 64-bit build.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's incredibly helpful.  I shall take a look tomorrow when I've had some sleep 8-)

Comment: wish you would have followed up to say what worked for you