# Virtualbox install 12.04 guest: "pae not present"

Tags: software-installation, virtualbox, pae

I get this message while trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 as a guest in VirutalBox 4.1.18, on an Ubuntu 10.04 host.

```
This kernel requires the following feature not present on the CPU: pae
```

Some host specs:

- The host's kernel is: `Linux 2.6.32-41-generic-pae GNU/Linux`
- lscpu (host): `Architecture: i686`, `CPU op-mode(s): 32-bit, 64-bit`
- `grep --color=always -i PAE /proc/cpuinfo`   does show `pae` in its output.

The 12.04 iso used is: *ubuntu-12.04.0-desktop-i386.iso*

As a comparison/check, I downloaded and installed Linux Mint 13 Cinnamon to the same host on the exact same VM (I just changed the .iso image). It worked fine. Its iso is: *linuxmint-13-cinnamon-dvd-32bit.iso*

It seems (to me) that I have **pae**.. what is going on here?

Update: I had assumed that Linux Mint also required **pae** (being Ubuntu based), but I've just run;   `grep --color=always -i PAE /proc/cpuinfo`   in the Mint VM.   It showed no output.   So it seems the issue may lie with VirtualBox.   If that is the case, how can I get Virtualbox into **pae** mode?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 comes with a [pae kernel as default](http://askubuntu.com/a/19390/3940). This may be different with Mint.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

On VirtualBox Manager, open your virtual machine configuration then select **System** on the left side and open the **Processor** tab. Be sure that **Enable PAE/NX** is checked.

[image]

For commandline

```
VBoxManage modifyvm <VM_name> --pae on
```