# pae kernel required for my cpu

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, windows-xp, pae

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install 12.04 on a non-PAE CPU? (error “Kernel requires features not present on the CPU: PAE”)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117744/how-can-i-install-12-04-on-a-non-pae-cpu-error-kernel-requires-features-not-p)
>   [Virtualbox install 12.04 guest: “pae not present”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163550/virtualbox-install-12-04-guest-pae-not-present)

After loading ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-i386.iso into my Oracle VM, the hard drive would not boot because the version for my cpu require the pae kernel.

How do I insert the pae kernel or download a copy of ubuntu with the pae kernel?