# Edubuntu inappropriate Kernel for installation

Tags: boot, kernel, virtualbox, edubuntu

I faced this error while Runnign Edubuntu from Virtual Box. 
  I used this edubuntu-13.04-dvd-i386.iso file.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VirtualBox is indicating that the PAE support is not present in your computer.  The following link may provide you with what you need to do to help with this situation. [Virtualbox install 12.04 guest: "pae not present"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163550/virtualbox-install-12-04-guest-pae-not-present)