# Should I install 64-bit Ubuntu on my Lenovo Ideapad Y510 laptop?

Tags: 64-bit

I have a [Lenovo IdeaPad Y510](http://www.cnet.com/laptops/lenovo-ideapad-y510/4507-3121_7-32815684.html) and I have Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit installed on it. I think my machine does support 64bit OS. Currently I have 1GB RAM and I am planning to upgrade it to 3-4 GB. After upgrading RAM can I install 64bit Ubuntu on my machine(for better performance as 64bit performs better than 32bit)? If yes then what [this](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/laptops-netbooks-minibooks/189753-so-do-i-have-32-bit-64-bit-system.html) link is talking about RAM usage. I didn't get it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only for support of more RAM an upgrade to 64-bit is not needed. In case you did a fresh install of 12.04 32-bit (i.e. no upgrade) you will already have a 32-bit [pae](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19389/whats-the-meaning-of-pae-at-the-end-of-kernel-version/19390#19390) kernel installed that supports up to 64 GB of RAM.

You can not "upgrade" 32-bit to 64-bit Ubuntu without re-installing the OS. This however may not be too much trouble in case you keep your HOME. If you decide to do that **please make a backup** of your important data before you proceed.

My personal recommendation in case you are happy with your installation, and you don't need to run 64-bit-only applications, would be to just leave your OS as it is. This is the least hazard to your data.